# PHP | How would I make my php script updater check for missed versions from a remote text file?

Tags: php

I am working on a PHP updater for my CMS project. What it does is it checks the remote *version.txt* file to see if it needs to update. My problem is, What is a user is still on version **1.0**, and the latest version defined in the remote *version.txt* file is **1.3**? How would I have my updater update to version **1.2** and then **1.3** in order? I provided my code below.

```
<?php

$phoenix_version = 1.0;
         $rc = @fsockopen("www.phoenix.ltda", 80, $errno, $errstr, 1);
        if (is_resource($rc))  {
        /* Update Version */
        $remote_version=trim(file_get_contents('https://phoenix.ltda/updates/version.txt'));
        $remote_version = preg_replace('/[^\\d.]+/', '', $remote_version);
        /* Current up to date version */
        $remote_current_version=trim(file_get_contents('https://phoenix.ltda/updates/current-version.txt'));
        $remote_current_version = preg_replace('/[^\\d.]+/', '', $remote_current_version);
        if(version_compare($remote_version, $phoenix_version) ==  1){
            $new_version = true;
        }else{
            $new_version = false; 
        }
        
        }else{
        echo "The Phoenix PHP updater could not be reached by this server. Please try again later or contact the Phoenix PHP team.";
        }
        
        
        if(!empty($_POST)) {
            $_POST['update'] = Database::clean_string($_POST['update']);
            $values['update'] = $_POST['update'];
            
            $clean_remote_version = preg_replace('/[.,]/', '', $remote_version);
            
            $ch = curl_init();
            $source = 'https://phoenix.ltda/updates/phoenix-update'.$clean_remote_version.'.zip';
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $source);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            $data = curl_exec ($ch);
            curl_close ($ch);

            $destination = ROOT_PATH . '/phoenix-update'.$clean_remote_version.'.zip';
            $file = fopen($destination, "w+");
            fputs($file, $data);
            fclose($file);

        }
?>
```

How would make it update in order to the latest version? Like 1.0 to 1.1 to 1.2 all the way to the latest version? What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not write some code to achieve all intermediate updates?

Comment: I guess where I am confused is how would update it in order like 1.0 to 1.1 to 1.2 and so on. @NicoHaase

Comment: What's your exact question about this? "How to update" is something you have to achieve in your application. "How to order" is simple: 1.0 to 1.1, 1.1 to 1.2 - or in any other way detemined by your application

Comment: How would I order the updates and then update them in order? Until it reaches the latest version? I am sorry if I am not clear.

Comment: What do you mean by "how"? Is there any problem in ordering from 1.0 over 1.1 to 1.2?

Comment: My concern is if a user misses update 1.0 and the latest version is 1.2. How do I get my script to update to 1.1 then to 1.2? @NicoHaase

Comment: That depends on your script. Why not run the update in a loop?

Answer (score 0):

If the update is barely a code update, this is a non-issue. But when there are several updates to the database, you need to write database migrations and run them one by one, version by version (checkout Laravel or Sphinx for good examples). Also your update script is quite over-complicated; better just post the current version onto an API and let it respond with an eventual updated version - this can also be used to send update batch URLs, instead of fetching a single file. Well, if the API only responds with the next one version (instead of the latest one), this would even work - but running all in a batch might be more elegant.